# A simple prolog syntax question

Tags: prolog

In user mode in SWI-Prolog I define a function as follows:

```
|: test1(+X,+Y) :- X >= 0, X =:= Y.
```

And now in query mode:

```
?- test1(1, 1).
false.
```

I was expecting this to return "true" since 1 is greater than 0 and 1 is equal to 1.

So where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you want instead:

```
test1(X,Y) :- X >= 0, X =:= Y.
```

And then:

```
?- test1(1, 1).
true.
```

Adding +, - and ? in front of predicate arguments is not part of Prolog. It is just a convention for documenting how predicates should be used.

Here is what the [GNU-prolog documentation](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc31) has to say:

> The mode specifies whether or not the argument must be instantiated when the built-in predicate is called. The mode is encoded with a symbol just before the type. Possible modes are:
>
> - +: the argument must be instantiated.
> - -: the argument must be a variable (will be instantiated if the built-in predicate succeeds).
> - ?: the argument can be instantiated or a variable.

In actual code, you should not prefix arguments with a +.